# How do I know how many instances of class are created at any given time in java?

Tags: java, oop

How do I know how many instances of class are created at any given time in java?
I have class A and I want to know how many instances are created at any given time?
Please let me know the solution

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How many instances - in a JVM, on a server, in the whole world?

Comment: @ppeterka66 - In the entire universe.

Comment: I tried using counter in constructor but I am looking for other way

Comment: @HotLicks ... and beyond...

Comment: "Please let me know the solution" -- You haven't stated a problem.

Comment: "Are created" - do you mean how many have been created since the program started running, or how many exist at the moment?

Comment: How many instances exist at the moment?

Comment: Only PhantomReference, only hardcore!

Answer (score 7):

Keep track of it in your constructor with a [static variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

```
public class A {

    private static int instances = 0;

    public A() {
        instances++;
    }
}
```

If [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) is a concern to you:

```
public class A {

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static int instances = 0;

    public A() {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            instances++;
        }
    }
}
```

To address what you've said in the comments below your question: if you want to know how many *currently exist* (i.e., have not been [garbage collected](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx)) you could try something like the following:

```
public class A {

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static int instances = 0;

    public A() {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            instances++;
        }
    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            instances--;
        }
    }
}
```

The `finalize()` method will be called right before the object is garbage collected.  However garbage collection is [notoriously unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/java-finalize-method-call).

Also, as a side note, you could use the `AtomicInteger` class rather than an `int` and the `synchronized` blocks, as @rolfl says below.  All upvotes for that idea should go to his answer, should he post one.

Comment: That's better (LOCK), now you have +1 from me too ;)

Comment: Is that better than `synchronized(A.class)`?

Comment: You beat me by 15 seconds ;-) Anyway, you might want to mention the factory pattern as well (as the typical way to deal with instance control).

Comment: Recommend `AtomicInteger` over the `LOCK`

Comment: @rolfl Nice point!  You should add it as an answer.  Don't want to take credit for your idea. :)  You'd have my +1.

Comment: Also call [`super.finalize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11379181/995891) (within a `finally` block)

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not such a bad question, you can control the number of instances by using sychronize and a counter, this design pattern is called instance-controlled class and it's one of the first things that are mentioned in "effective Java" by Joshua Bloch (chapter 2)

Comment: Of course, there's no way to count the instances that are collected.

Comment: @HotLicks sorry but I didn't understand your comment (the collected part).

Comment: One can attempt to subtract the garbage-collected objects with a `finalize` method, but it's highly unreliable.  So the total number in existence at any one point in time is not knowable without using "instruments".

Comment: @HotLicks but that's another question (how many LIVE objects are there) - the original question was how many instances were created ;)

Comment: How many instances *ARE* created.  That can be interpreted either way.  And later he says "How many instances exist at the moment".

Comment: @HotLicks yeps, I guess you're right - it can be interpreted either way

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way, but if you're really interested in keeping track of this information you could create a `private static int instanceCounter` field and increment it in your constructor(s).  You would also need a `finalize` method which would decrement the counter whenever an instance is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement a counter when it inits